# Rails 3: scaffold destroy action redirect to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, action, scaffold

i created a simple scaffold, the problem is that when i try to delete a record click destroy rails redirect to the show action, this is the code of the link generated automatically when i generate the scaffold:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have `rails.js` included in your application layout, as this link require JS to use the correct HTTP method. Also make sure you have the `csrf_meta_tag` in your layout.

Comment: ok thanks now that jquery library and other js file are commented and with <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> destroy action works but how can i include jquery and prototype togheter with no conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your `application.js` has `//= require jquery_ujs`

Answer (score 0):

Add in `application.js` this code

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```